# What is the difference in saving the model as cnn.model or cnn.h5?How are these extensions different?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am using `model.save("cnn.model")` and `model.save("cnn.h5")` to save the model after training.

What is the difference of the saving the model in 2 different extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File name, which includes the extension, doesn't matter. Whatever it is, Keras will save a HDF5 formatted model into that file.

Doc: [How can I save a Keras model?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

> You can use `model.save(filepath)` to save a Keras model into a single
>   HDF5 file which will contain:
>
> - the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model
> - the weights of the model
> - the training configuration (loss, optimizer)
> - the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.